# Nagios Wrapper Script that Checks board

Tags: linux, nagios

I am in need of a kind of automation script or program run in the `Linux` environment that can check my Nagios board and can display results or store it's results of the Host, Service, Description, etc in a text file. Can anyone provide me with what kind of program works well with this?

Instead of blatantly downvoting my question, can you suggest what may need to be changed in order to better word my question?!

Comment: Sorry, what are you talking about...  Product recommendations are off topic, but your question doesn't really make sense.  It isn't cleare what you want.

Comment: I am looking to see if there is a wrapper script I can run on Linux that can actively check my nagios board and display it's results

Comment: Basically I am looking to view the same results I would see on the board in a text format in Linux

Comment: cat `/var/cache/nagios3/status.dat`.

Comment: This might work, I just gotta figure out where nagios is saved on our server

Comment: Maybe nagstamon is something that would fit you needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an [entire category of so-called "front end" add-ons](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Frontends-%28GUIs-and-CLIs%29) in Nagios Exchange, including some CLI interfaces.

You also might want to look at the [APIs category](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/APIs) if you need something more granular or specific than a CLI frontend can provide.

Answer (score -1):

nagiosstats might do the trick.

> The utility called nagiostats is included in the Nagios distribution. It is compiled and installed along with the main Nagios daemon. The nagiostats utility allows you to obtain various information about a running Nagios process that can be very helpful in tuning performance.

http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/nagiostats.html

Comment: nagiosstats will give you internal stats about the performance of Nagios, which I don't think is what is really being asked here.